# reading from stdin using select() - in a nonblocking way

Tags: c++, linux, stdin, nonblocking

i'm writing a program that perform server-client relations.
In the program, i'm using `select()` in order to get the client's requests, and also the user's requests(the one behind the server) from the stdin.
What it seems to be is that the `select()` works fine for the client's requests, but doesn't seem to respond to the input from the `stdin`.
Also, i don't succeed to `recv()` from the `stdin`.
Is there a way to get an input from the stdin in a non-blocking way? I've tried using `fgets()` instead of `select()`, and tho i've set the `fcntl()` to be non-blocking, it doesn't seem to work - it is still blocking.

What do you suggest?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post some code based on how have you tried?

Comment: winsock means windows? ;) I thought select() is for sockets only on Windows, file handlers cannot be processed via select, but it is possible on Unixes where you could get file descriptor and add it to FD_SET

Comment: What is stdin connected to: regular file? pipe? socket? How is it opened? Try posting a small program that exhibits the problem.

Answer (score 1):

stdin is line-buffered - you cannot read from it in a non-blocking way.

Comment: Line buffering is a function of C or C++ standard library streams, and has no meaning at the level of POSIX I/O system calls such as `recv()` and `select()`.  For `stdin` in the question, read `STDIN_FILENO` if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [kbhit](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/kbhit.html) to see if there are any characters on the input buffer ready to be read.

In the event you do not have access to `kbhit`, here is a simple implementation I have used in the past:

```
int kbhit() {
   int count = 0;
   struct termios otty, ntty;
   tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &otty);
   ntty = otty;
   ntty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
   if(tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &ntty) == 0) {
      ioctl(STDIN_FILENO, FIONREAD, &count);
      tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &otty);
   }
   return count;
}
```